# React-Redux async functions using thunk not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Types.js File:

```
const ADD_TOKENS = "ADD_TOKENS";

export { ADD_TOKENS};
```

Actions.js File:

```
import { ADD_TOKENS } from "./types";

function addTokens() {
  return {
    type: ADD_TOKENS,
  };
}

const actionCreators = {
  addTokens,
};

export { actionCreators };
```

Reducers.js File

```
import { ADD_TOKENS } from "./types";
import getTokens from "../../api/getTokens";

const initialState = {
  access_token: null,
  refresh_token: null,
  expiration_time: null,
};

function applyAddTokens(state) {
  console.log("Function being hit"); //yes
  return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log("Function being hit"); //no
    const token = await getTokens();
    return {
      ...state,
      access_token: dispath(token.access_token),
      refresh_token: dispath(token.refresh_token),
      expiration_time: dispath(token.expiration_time),
    };
  };
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TOKENS:
      return applyAddTokens(state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

index.js File

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { actionCreators as actions } from "./actions";

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    const { addTokens } = this.props;
    console.log("Props in Login/index.js", this.props);
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={addTokens}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { access_token, refresh_token, expiration_time } = state;
  return {
    access_token,
    refresh_token,
    expiration_time,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addTokens: bindActionCreators(actions.addTokens, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

store.js File

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "../components/Login/reducers";

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

Why is this not working? Why is `applyAddTokens` function's thunk not producing anything? Let me know if anyone needs any additional details. `getTokens()` returns an object that contains access_token, refresh_token, and expiration_time. This worked before when I tried it without async (just regular data without any request).

Answer (score 0):

Your code flow is like below:

- In your JSX, upon onPress, you trigger the action `addTokens`.
- This action returns an object of type `ADD_TOKENS`
- Redux will directly execute the reducer (the `ADD_TOKENS` switch case). Here you are calling an async function `applyAddTokens`.
- Redux will execute it IMMEDIATELY (without waiting for promise result) and returns the output of `applyAddTokens` function which is a `pending promise`
- That's it.

**Solution**

- First, put [all async code in your actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators). Keep reducers light and use it only to update state.
- To use thunk, your action must return a function (not an object).
- [See this example as well](https://medium.com/@User3141592/understanding-the-redux-thunk-source-code-b3f8b930faf6)